# bootstrap 4 datepicker, calendar icon don't show up

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, calendar, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use datapicker with Bootstrap 4, the input display correctly the big calendar where I can select the date, the date format is also correct as I expected, the only thing I can't display is the little calendar icon next to the input field.
Can you please suggest?

Here is the code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    $('[name="date"]')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // do somwthing here
        });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <form id="demoForm" action="success.html" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you are using additional bootstrap datepicker?Bootstrap 4 default datepicker is good and looks similar to bootstrap-datepicker.Just write `<input type='date'/>`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that to be honest, can you please supply the code?

Comment: I added my answer below

Comment: @MarcelloPerri Using `type=date`  will not suitable for you only if you want send the date backend it will like `dd/mm/yyyy`  - the default format of input type="date" us `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: I could always format the date in PHP before storing the information in the database, but the point is that the calendar-icon didn't show up with bootstrap datapicker.

Comment: You have to add a calender icon manually via HTML. It not a part of the boostrap library

Comment: oh, that's a bit disappointing, why to use a Framework if I have to do things manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using font-awsome.css, without using `input type="date"` and only adding this html tag after the text input `<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>`.

here is the code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    $('[name="date"]')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // do somwthing here
        });
});
```

```css
.fa {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 11px;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="demoForm" action="success.html" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
         </form>
         
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="demoForm" action="success.html" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" />
                </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes, however in database the date will stored in yyyy-mm-dd format only.Then i think it will not be a problem.